# Windows 10 Error Message Location for editing

Tags: windows-10, user-profile

Does anyone know the location of this error message, so I can edit the text?

[image]

I tried searching the registry and the .vbs files in the C:\windows\ directory, but wasn't able to find any reference to that error.

Answer (score 1):

This error message is in the translation subsystem database as a (non-readable) binary string.

You **definately should not edit** this critical system component, as those files are all signed and can be overwritten at any point by updates. You would most probably destroy your Windows installation.

Additionally, the text content in this message is clear and correct. There shouldn't be any need to "change" it.